# Sharing file in Oreo not working

Tags: android, file, android-intent, android-8.0-oreo, file-sharing

I'm trying to share an audio file in Oreo. If the file is in internal storage of the device, it runs fine but if the file is present on the external storage it crashes giving this exception - android.os.FileUriExposedException.

How to solve this problem:

```
public void shareSong(SongInfoModel songInfoModel){

    Uri uri = Uri.parse("");
    File f = new File(songInfoModel.getData());
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<=Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1) {
          uri = Uri.parse("file://" + f.getAbsolutePath());
    }else {
         uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", f);
    }
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    share.setType("audio/*");
    share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share audio File"));

}
```

Manifest:

```
 <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

Comment: What is your OS that you are using to send the file to? Is this client support SMB?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an app that shares files with other apps using a Uri, you may have encountered this error on API 24+.

**Step 1**

add provider to your manifest file

```
<manifest ...>
<application ...>
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
</application>
```

**Step 2**

Create XML file res/xml/provider_paths.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

**Step 3**

add new code

```
    File file ; // your code
    Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    install.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    // Old Approach
    install.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), mimeType);
    // End Old approach
    // New Approach
    Uri apkURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            context,
            context.getApplicationContext()
                    .getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
    install.setDataAndType(apkURI, mimeType);
    install.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    // End New Approach
    context.startActivity(install);
```

Comment: It is only happening with audio files on external SD card or external storage. Files on internal storage share just fine.

Comment: Sharing video files is not working, do you have any workaround for this issue?