# Google Play does not accept my actions schema

Tags: android, apk, google-play-console

I recently fixed a bug in my Android App enabling sharing of files for the Oreo & Pie OS (8.0 & 9.0). However, after adding the code to my app from this post - [Sharing file in Oreo not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51121149/sharing-file-in-oreo-not-working):, and changing the version number I tried uploading my app to the Google Play Store only to get this message:

[image]

I am really confused by this error message.

1. First of all how do I whitelist my developer account?
2. The error message states that my bundle has an actions.xml file, but I don't see an actions.xml file in my project.
3. Lastly, it tells me to accept the Actions on Google Terms of Service in the Consent section of the Pricing and Distribution page, but I do not see an accept Actions option on that page.

Please help me, I do not know how to resolve this.

Comment: Why don't you talk to Google about it?

Comment: I am currently, will give updates.

Comment: Just got done chatting with Google Assistant for 30 minutes. They didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was finally able to upload my APK to Google Play store after removing these lines of code from the manifest file:

```
<meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.actions" 
     android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
```

Notice the name has 'actions' in it, and according to Google you can't use the actions schema in the Android manifest yet.

Comment: Have you been able to test your app actions with speech commands?